# Where is the DVWP in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, data-view-web-part

Salvete!  Where can I find the *Data View Web Part* in Sharepoint Enterprise 2010?

I can't see anywhere to enable it as a feature, and it doesn't show up in any of the web-part lists.  [I understand](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12742/data-view-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010#12751) it is also called *XSLT List View*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plases follow these instructions to get it ;)

> 1. Open your SharePoint Page and in Site Actions select ->Edit in SharePoint Designer.
> 2. Now select a zone on teh Page where you want to add your Dataview weboart.
> 3. Next, click on Insert tab -> click on Data View.
> 4. In the drop-down of Data view menu click on “Empty Data view” . This will now insert an Empty Data view in your selected zone.
> 5. Next click on “click here to select datasource” to select the datasource or list.
> 6. Select the list\library you want to display the data from.
> 7. Next drag and drop the columns in the dataview webpart from the right hand column list (for the list\library you selected).

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/10/16/create-dataview-webpart-in-sharepoint-2010-tutorial/

another step by step guide with images:

http://www.bybugday.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=30

You need sharepoint designer or do it from code ;)

hope it helps :)

Comment: Ah!  I was always trying to insert a *web-part*! It is called `data view web part` but isn't listed with the web-parts!  Got it!  Thank you for the nice answer.